# tmux not working with Bash

Tags: bash, osx, tmux

I am using macOS with `tmux` downloaded from source and Homebrew. When starting `tmux` both times I installed it, it gives me a blank screen with the bar at the bottom. I can use `tmux` commands but a `bash` shell does not open. Is there something I need to do to get a `bash`/terminal to run inside `tmux`?

Comment: How do you start `tmux`? Do you have a `tmux` configuration file?

Comment: Is there a good reason to compile the sources yourself? How did you do that? What configuration file are you using for `tmux`?

Comment: I compiled from source to see if anything would change from downloading it with home-brew. I followed the readme to download and make it, and the config file I used was either the example one or none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who responded, you were all a help. In the end there was a command in my bash_profile file which made the screen blank. Sorry to waste valuable time.